# Python gcd calulation of rsa

Tags: python, rsa, greatest-common-divisor

```
def gcd(e, z):

    if z == 0:
        return e
    else:
        return gcd(z, e % z)

e = int(input("Please enter the first number:"))
z = int(input("Please enter the second number:"))

print ("The GCD of ",e," and ",z," is ",gcd(e,z))
d = 1
while d < e:

    if d * e == 1 % z:
        print (d," * ",e," = 1 (mod ",z,")")
        d = d + 1
    else:
        d = d + 1
```

I am trying to use this code to find candidates for rsa by brute force it seems like it should work but it doesn't can anyone help me out?

z = (p − 1)(q − 1)
for the calculation of z is used prior to this
with  p = 47 and q = 59, e = 17 and d = 157 but after the program runs it finds no matches but it should.

Comment: `1 % z` is always `1` ... what did you expect this to mean?

Comment: i was expecting de = 1 (mod z)

Comment: Then you want `(d*e)%z==1`

Comment: If @khelwood's comment isn't obvious: `1 (mod z)` is always 1 (for `z > 1`). But `de (mod z)` is not always `de`. So you're doing the modulus remainder on the wrong side. (Of course technically speaking, you should do it on _both_ sides, but the point is, you can skip the right, and you can't skip the left.)

Comment: if z = (p-1)(q-1), then gcd(e, z) is always 1, what is the point of your first function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have

```
if d * e == 1 % z:
```

you seem to want to check "*Is `d*e` equal (mod `z`) to `1`*"

But what you're doing is performing `1 % z` (which gives `1`) and checking if `d * e` is equal to `1`.

Change it to:

```
if (d*e) % z == 1:
```

and it should do the calculation you intend.

Answer (score 0):

some problems from your code:

1) if z = (p-1)(q-1), d*e = 1 (mod z), then z and e are coprime, gcd(e, z) will always equal 1, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation)

2) if you say d*e = 1 (mod z), the code should be `if d * e % z == 1`

Comment: Your (3) isn't necessary. If you pass them in the wrong order, then `e%z` will be `e`, as you say, but that just means the `return gcd(z, e%z)` is the same as `return gcd(z, e)`. In other words, it automatically swaps them for you.

Comment: that is what I meant, he would never get the greatest common divisor@abarnert

Comment: Then you meant wrong. If you call `gcd(e, z)` when you should have called `gcd(z, e)`, that's fine, because the first thing it will do is `return gcd(z, e)`. Try running it; `gcd(4, 18)` and `gcd(18, 4)` both return `2`.